# What if I don't declare an ID in <div>?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html

How can I access any `<div>` if I don't declare the `id` attribute. Does DOM create ID itself?

e.g.

```
<div class="common_class" onmouseover="know_your_div(this)">
</div>

<script type="text/script">
   function know_your_div(obj){
     /* 
     Here i want to access the div object not by class because of it's common
     for all div
     */
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Inside the function, does not the "obj" argument give you access to the div? What happens when you try to access, say, obj.style.width? Did you try it?

Comment: @pete i tried and it's working.  e.g. obj.parentNode.SOME_Method(); but at large scale i need to specify/identify the particular DIV.

Comment: @user, if by "at large scale" you mean you want to reference the div as a global in some other section of code outside of the function "know_your_div(obj)" then why do you not want to save "obj" in some global somewhere? Like: var div_at_large_scale; function know_your_div(obj) { div_at_large_scale = obj; ... }

Comment: @Pete, ohh really? but according to my understanding if you save any OBJECT in Variable then state of OBJECT might be change in string/var. I mean the actual state of OBJECT would be loss somehow. Whether i am not sure if we can that way otherwise it'd be perfect solution. Big thanks to you.

Comment: @pete, resolved. Please note: var div_at_large_scale = **"must be initialized"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your Question,  let me try to help you

```
<div class="common_class" onmouseover="know_your_div(this)"> </div>

var oldObject = "";
function know_your_div(obj) {

  // write ur condition if/ese/while/..

    obj.parentNode.do_Something(); OR obj.parentNode.ID/Class/value

    oldObject = obj;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the answer to your question is right there in your code.

The `obj` parameter that your `know_your_div` function takes is supplied as `this` in the `onmouseover` attribute. Thus, that is your `div`.

Comment: that is what i am trying since morning but now i am pulling out my hair  :)  what when you have many many div in that case this method got stuck in  middle sometimes....

Answer (score 3):

There's not an easy way to get to it in all browsers.  Your best bet is to just create an ID on it.  Is there a reason you can't?

Short of that, you have to navigate to it using DOM traversal methods, which are horribly unstable if your DOM structure changes at all.  Code like:

```
document.body.childNodes[3].childNodes[2].childNodes[4];
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[22]; // 23rd DIV in the page
```

etc...

Comment: I was just writing the same answer :) +1 for being quick! And, obviously, in my mind 'right'... :D

Comment: i knew that.  actually i am writing one function for those kind of div where developers forget to write the id.  can't we do that like this : this.parentNode ???

Answer (score 0):

then I guess you need to specify the ID explicitly alongside the class name..DOM won't create the ID itself...

Answer (score 0):

Then it's time to use the DOM. Maybe you could use things like firstChild, lastChild, nextSibling.. http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/node.htm

If you're using a JS library, like MooTools or jQuery, which I reccomend, you'll have a lot of powerful selector magic at your hands (example http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Slick.Finder).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JQuery and selectors?
http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: It would work, but this isn't a jQuery question - therefore I think jQuery isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the DOM does not create an ID. You need to add an ID. You can use jQuery to access a div by it's class.